# Pivot Table Average summary returns error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table, crosstab

I'm creating a very simple analysis of attendance at my membership organisation meetings. We have a meeting register in excel with 3 columns:

1. MeetingDate
2. Person
3. Category (member or visitor)

So I create a simple crosstab, with meetingdate for the rows and Category for the columns, and count(person) for the values

The data is fine (see screenshot) except the column totals are slightly meaningless. What would be much better is to have column averages.

When I choose "Summarize by average" in the context menu, the entire crosstab shows #DIV/0! values.

Any suggestions as to why? And as to how I can show average instead of sum in the bottom row ?

[image]

Comment: Could you please [Edit] your post & add the formula/function you have been used so far!

Comment: if looking help for PT then instead fo SUM apply AVERAGE.

Comment: I don't know what PT is?

Comment: The formula in the crosstab is count(person) as I said above

Comment: You mean across Sheets?

Comment: PT is Pivot Table (your Screen Shot).

Comment: Your data does not have any VALUES, you cannot take an average of text stings, you need numerical data

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you don't have a column with number values to average, so the error is actually correct. You are not able to create an average for data that is not numeric. There is no average when you look at the actual data (person 1, person 2, etc.) The easiest way to get an average would be to just create your own formula... `=AVERAGE(cell range)`

[image: See example here]

Comment: I must be missing something here. The count(person) figure is the number of attendees in each row. And the total columns and total rows are displaying sum(count(person) in each row/column). Why can't it display average(count(person) in each row/column)?

Comment: Because you are not summing a string of values. you are counting text entries. You cannot create an average number from a string of text. you can count the number of text entries, but you cannot average them.

Comment: And the right hand total column is not a total of the text values. Its a total (sum) of the count values. So why cant that total be an average instead of a sum?